# Print each dictionary from a list in a new line in a string

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a string and a list of dictionaries:

```
body = "Next, we wil give you detailed information about each case: %s"

feature_list = [{'FEATURE_NAME': 'FT02', 'Number of users who tested it ': 30, 'Number of problems detected' : 2},
{'FEATURE_NAME': 'SW045', 'Number of users who tested it ': 5, 'Number of problems detected' : 0}
{'FEATURE_NAME': 'SW04',  'Number of users who tested it ': 23, 'Number of problems detected' : 8}]
```

I want to create a new string like this :

```
newbody = """
    Next, we wil give you detailed information about each case :
    {'FEATURE_NAME': 'FT02', 'Number of users who tested it ': 30, 'Number of problems detected' : 2}
    {'FEATURE_NAME': 'SW045', 'Number of users who tested it ': 5, 'Number of problems detected' : 0}
    {'FEATURE_NAME': 'SW049',  'Number of users who tested it ': 23, 'Number of problems detected' : 8}]
    """
```

I tried to iterate over the list but with this i only get the last dictionary in the string. I know it's possible to give the list as it is but that looks very ugly and hard to read.

Comment: Can you show us how you tried to iterate and what you got as a result, compared to what you "want" to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

join items in `feature_list`, then print

```
body = "Next, we wil give you detailed information about each case:"

feature_list = [{'FEATURE_NAME': 'FT02', 'Number of users who tested it ': 30, 'Number of problems detected' : 2},
{'FEATURE_NAME': 'SW045', 'Number of users who tested it ': 5, 'Number of problems detected' : 0},
{'FEATURE_NAME': 'SW04',  'Number of users who tested it ': 23, 'Number of problems detected' : 8}]
features = '\n'.join(str(feature) for feature in feature_list)
print(f'{body}\n{features}')
```

Note, it will be much better to make a nice string instead of display dict.